# Ubuntu 22.04 Stuck before shutdown

Tags: gnome, shutdown, 22.04

I am having the issue that my laptop does neither power off nor reboot - and it never did right from the first startup after installation - it's just stuck at somewhat random lines like (sorry for just writing down screen output manually):

```
systemd-shutdown[1]: Powering off.
```

or

```
kvm: exiting hardware virtualization
```

or

```
Worker [int] processing [...] is taking [...]
```

or

```
[...] waiting for process: systemd-udevd, systemd-udevd, systemd-udevd [...]
```

Output also prints (before those lines though):

```
[...]
[  OK  ] Finished System Power Off.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Power Off.
```

Also, I don't seem to notice any failures during shutdown

I installed Ubuntu Minimal from a bootable USB key (https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso), alongside a Win11 installation.

```
michael@go:~ $ sudo lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop2         7:2    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1518
loop3         7:3    0 155.6M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1232
loop4         7:4    0 400.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop5         7:5    0 248.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop6         7:6    0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop7         7:7    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop8         7:8    0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/575
loop9         7:9    0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/582
loop10        7:10   0  43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15177
loop11        7:11   0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16010
loop12        7:12   0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/10
loop13        7:13   0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14
sda           8:0    1  29.3G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    1  29.3G  0 part /media/michael/UBUNTU 22_0
mmcblk0     179:0    0 119.3G  0 disk /media/michael/SD_Storage
nvme0n1     259:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  58.3G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   890M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  59.8G  0 part /
```

Funny thing is that when I run Ubuntu from the USB key (Try Ubuntu), the laptop successfully shuts down (upon hitting enter after being asked to remove the installation medium).

My hardware is a Microsoft Surface Go 2

```
michael@go:~ $ sudo lscpu 
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  4
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) m3-8100Y CPU @ 1.10GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               142
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  2
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            9
    CPU max MHz:         3400.0000
    CPU min MHz:         400.0000
    BogoMIPS:            3199.92
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse
                         36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb
                          rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopo
                         logy nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl
                          vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic 
                         movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm
                          3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stib
                         p tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bm
                         i1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_p
                         t xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_noti
                         fy hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features: 
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   64 KiB (2 instances)
  L1i:                   64 KiB (2 instances)
  L2:                    512 KiB (2 instances)
  L3:                    4 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
  L1tf:                  Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnera
                         ble
  Mds:                   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Meltdown:              Mitigation; PTI
  Mmio stale data:       Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional,
                          RSB filling
  Srbds:                 Mitigation; Microcode
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

Graphics:

```
michael@go:~ $ sudo lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 615 (rev 02)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 21)
```

Currently on

```
michael@go:~ $ uname -r
5.15.0-40-generic
```

I quickly had access to a Surface Go 2 model with an Intel Pentium CPU. The system shut down and rebooted successfully.

On my journey of research I tried different grub configurations (acpi=force, apm=power_off), although tbh, I'm not sure what they actually do.

I also came across a post suggesting disabling kvm and kvm_intel modules, which I tried too, without success.

I'm running out of ideas, so maybe someone has any. Let me know what info is missing to get a clue.

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem two days in a row with debian installation, I have tried the most common solutions for that, which are: **unload and blacklist kvm modules**.
The bugs were not fixed and I was still getting any of these errors:

`systemd-shutdown[1]: Powering off.` or

`kvm: exiting hardware virtualization` or

`Worker [int] processing [...] is taking [...]` or

`[...] waiting for process: systemd-udevd, systemd-udevd, systemd-udevd [...]`

I was able to solve that bug, what I did was to **unload and blacklist** the built-in (*in my case nouveau, for debian or debian based distros*)

**first open terminal and copy the whole command to unload and blacklist the nouveau driver**(make sure you know which are the proprietary drivers for your gpu):

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
blacklist nouveau

blacklist lbm-nouveau

options nouveau modeset=0

alias nouveau off

alias lbm-nouveau off

EOF
```

**press enter and then copy this again**:

`echo options nouveau modeset=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf`

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

then put the commands to replace with proprietary gpu drivers, in my case was *nvidia*:

`sudo apt install nvidia-detect`

`sudo nvidia-detect`

`sudo apt install [detected-driver-name]`

or

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver`

after that, i was able to shut down or reboot without any problem

If you are using nvidia graphics cards, I recommend you this page https://docs.kinetica.com/7.1/install/nvidia_deb/ , here are the steps to unload and blacklist nouveau and replace with proprietary drivers

Comment: Hi lykkos. Thanks for your input. I cannot verify your suggestions for a) I replaced the Surface Go with a more powerful UMPC (GPD Pocket3 i7), b) I switched over to Manjaro (with Cinnamon) which seems rather bullet proof in this regard and c) my graphics hardware is Intel based. However, maybe your reply helps other out there...