# Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS stuck on power-off/reboot screen

Tags: boot, 22.04, shutdown

My system is not shutting down / rebooting propperly since a couple days, it gets stuck a the black screen with the dell and ubuntu logos. Only way to shut down is to hold the power button for 5 seconds.

I tried the solutions mentioned in following issues without success.

- [Ubuntu 22.04 stuck at shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426205/ubuntu-22-04-stuck-at-shutdown)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029068/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-at-shutdown?newreg=4f5908f34c2f4917902e976e50a35490)

`journalctl -b -1 -r` output:

```
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd-journald[380]: Journal stopped
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining proce>
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devi>
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Reached target System Reboot.
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Finished System Reboot.
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: systemd-reboot.service: Deactivated success>
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File System>
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated suc>
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador kernel: br-db8700e41dbb: port 3(vetha3b8e0d) entered di>
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador kernel: device vetha3b8e0d left promiscuous mode
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /swapfile.
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated succe>
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactiv>
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /swapfile...
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador kernel: br-db8700e41dbb: port 2(veth13b5c46) entered di>
Aug 14 10:28:12 Mogador kernel: device veth13b5c46 left promiscuous mode
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add links to the solutions you tried. Is there anything suspicious in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: The instruction in following post solved my issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416573/ubuntu-22-04-stuck-before-shutdown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 Stuck before shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416573/ubuntu-22-04-stuck-before-shutdown)